# Keystroke to preview a file Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

In OS X, selecting an icon, then pressing the <kbd>space</kbd> will show  the contents of the file in a 'preview' pane.

Is there an equivalent in Windows 7?

I am aware of Explorer's preview pane, but that's one more step in the process (I might as well open the file).

Comment: "I am aware of Explorer's preview pane, but that's one more step in the process (I might as well open the file)."  How so?  You click on the file to select it, and it shows you a preview.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not supported in Windows 7 without any third party applications.

The hotkey `Alt + P`, when used in Windows Explorer, will open up the Preview Pane and essentially does the same thing.